# can there be any problems with building full featured jquery file manager for asp.net?

Tags: jquery

I m building a file manager...and i m doing that in jquery instead of using asp.net server controls. until now everything is going just fine and the file manager looks cool and works well.

I m concerned if there are any possible bottlenecks with using jquery for file management when  switched to production environment???

thnks in advance for your replies....

Comment: jquery runs on client side .. so you might have problem with browser rather than with server. And best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, as I can find when googling this, no worries of using jQuery to handle file management.

in my previous company, we built such one using ExtJS , and comparing that ExtJS is HUGE and not as fast as jQuery, we found the file manager to work very fine, and the customer was very happy.

go on, and tell us about the result.